# How to read X86 hit miss cache registers with C

Tags: c, caching, x86

Can you give me any simple example? I know that exist special tools, but I want integrate it in my code.
I want collect some statistics. Also I need see when some bad situation happens.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

The data you are looking for may be available in your processor's performance monitoring counters (PMCs), which can be read using the `rdpmc` instruction. However, there are a number of major "gotchas" involving them, which all point to it being inappropriate for you to use them in your code:

1. **The layout of these counters is CPU model specific.** Each model of processor has a different set of counters available. Code which works correctly for one model will probably not work correctly for another — unless you have the ability to test against a very large set of machines, you cannot be sure that your code will work reliably.
2. **Performance counters are not always made available to userspace applications.** Some operating systems do not set the PCE bit in CR4, which will cause `rdpmc` to throw a fault when executed. You haven't mentioned what operating system you are working with here, so I can't say whether this will be an issue for you.
3. **The contents of the performance counters are highly esoteric.** Even I don't understand them well. The question you've posed here ("read X86 hit miss cache registers") suggests that you have a relatively limited understanding of the architecture, so it is unlikely that you will find them much more meaningful than I do.

Unless you have an extremely compelling reason to read this data from your application, don't. Leave them alone. Use a dedicated profiling tool instead.

Comment: Also note that before you can `rdpmc` you have to configure them (tell the counter what to measure); and to configure them (at least, if the kernel doesn't provide an API to do it for you) you need to use the `wrmsr` instruction that can only be used at CPL=0.

Comment: Each model of processor has a different set of counters available. Yes, but at the same time different CPU should have some common registers which I can read. If I try to read some nonexistent registers I should get a zero value and all. It should not affect on reliability of the code.

Comment: @Serg: That would be nice if it were true, but it isn't. Performance counters differ *significantly* between CPU models, and MSRs have been reused across models in some cases.

Comment: I have AMD CPU and Linux RedHat only. Why I should worry about different type of CPUs? The problem is about how to use C code in my programm to collect some statistics about hardware performance counters and nothing more. Exist a lot of programs which can do it. But I try to find any information about it with some simple examples.

Comment: Probably using AMD CodeXL, CodeAnalyst will be better for AMD CPU, because it comes from AMD. CodeAnalyst is built on OProfile for the Linux platform and is available as a free download.